# My python program gets input and output is blank

Tags: python, input, output

```
import os
import time

class student:
    def __init__(self):
    self.name=""

    def inp(self):
        print "This is student record program"
        self.Name = raw_input("Enter the name: ")
        self.ID = input("Enter the ID :")
        self.Age = raw_input("Enter the age: ")
        self.Mark = [input("Enter marks one by one ") for i in range(3)]
        self.total = sum(self.Mark)

    def dis(self):
        print "Name: ".format(self.Name)
        print "ID: ".format(self.ID)
        print "Age: ".format(self.Age)
        for i in range(3):
            print "Mark :".format(self.Mark[i])
        print "Total: ".format(self.total)

stu1=student()
stu1.inp()
stu1.dis()
```

This is my code. Please help me.
I tried to get student details and print it using class
But the output is blank 
I am new to python
I don't know where i went wrong.

Comment: `.format` doesn't append any data.  It needs a format string.  Read through the documentation carefully. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 1):

```
    print "Name: ".format(self.Name)
```

`format` strings require curly brackets to indicate where the inserted values should go.

```
    print "Name: {}".format(self.Name)
```

After adding the brackets, the output will be:

```
This is student record program
Enter the name: a
Enter the ID :1
Enter the age: 2
Enter marks one by one 1
Enter marks one by one 2
Enter marks one by one 3
Name: a
ID: 1
Age: 2
Mark: 1
Mark: 2
Mark: 3
Total: 6
```

Comment: I still get blank output

Comment: Can you run my program and check?

Comment: Sure. Works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the python String Formatting Operators `%s %d %f etc`

[String Formatting Operators](https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

```
def dis(self):
    print "Name: %s" % self.Name
    print "ID: %s" %self.ID
    print "Age: %s" % self.Age
    for i in range(3):
        print "Mark : %s" % self.Mark[i]
    print "Total: %s" % self.total
```